# Altium: Component Clearance constraint won't go away after setting rule

Tags: pcb, altium, layout, drc

I am using Altium 18. I ran a DRC check and got the following error:
[image]

This is saying i don't have clearance between J2 and MH2. This can be seen in the PCB:
[image]

However, i have set the following rule:
[image]

Surely this should get rid of this error? What am i missing?

Comment: What does the 3D render look like?

Comment: Did you check the rule priority?

Comment: Ah it was the rule priority! The standard rule had a higher priority than this one. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have another rule defined.

From your first image you can see the violated rule has the name "ComponentClearance" which I guess is set to match all objects.

Check your rules again for duplicated rules with different names, I also would suggest checking your rule priorities.

Remove/edit the rule with the name "ComponentClearance" or set it to a lower priority, and you should be fine.

Comment: Yes it was rule priority. This rule had a lower priority than the standard clearance that had been set.. Thanks.